# How to change chart's x axis interval

Tags: c#, charts

I have a data for each day, there are multiple data entries occuring. 
If I want to show this as a stackarea chart, excel does this in a perfect way, i.e. displays the date interval on x axis evenly. 
When I try to do this with MS Charting tool, the interval of on x axis becomes effected by the number of the entries. 
03/08/10 36 94
04/08/10 26 104
04/08/10 26 104
05/08/10 28 102
05/08/10 28 102
05/08/10 35 95
05/08/10 35 95

Any ideas, how I can tell AxisX will have a fixed interval?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks Rice, but it was the intervaltype I have to tell the days:
`chartCheck.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Days;`

Answer (score 14):

If you are using the Microsoft .net charting tools, then your chart has a "ChartArea"  Se

Set `ChartArea.AxisX.Interval` to 1.  You will have an interval with a label at each data point.